# Actuator and Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

Using the `gs-actuator-service` sample I get `{}` output from the `actuator/info` endpoint and just `{status="Ok"}` from the `actuator/health` endpoint.

From reading on the web it seems that more info is returned if the user is authenticated. I added the security starter dependency to the 'gs-actuator-service' sample but could't get any more information from the endpoints. Should the endpoints return more and if so how do I add security to the sample and get the additional info?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for getting more info

If using gradle add the following

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

see the Integrating with Actuator section of https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/ for more information.